# Script for downloading Medline abstracts with PMID

Tags: python, r, web-scraping

I am looking for a script that will enable me to download a set of abstracts (or article meta-data of an article) from PubMed by supplying it with a list of PubMed ID (PMID) numbers (e.g., from a .csv file).  The ideal script would be for R and then Python, but I am certainly open to any solutions or suggestions.  PubMed can be found [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed).

As a side note, I did find an older package called MedlineR, but this package never made it to Bioconductor, and there doesn't seem to be any recent chatter on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the RISmed package which seems to do what you want. 
This is cribbed from the manual.

```
require("RISmed")
res <- EUtilsSummary("myeloma[ti] jones[au]")
summary(res)

Query:
myeloma[ti] AND jones[au] 

Result count:  66

fetch <- EUtilsGet(res)
PMID(fetch)
> [1] "25188537" "25181509" "25042852" ...
AbstractText(fetch)[[1]]
[1] "The cause of follicular spicules in multiple myeloma (MM) is not known."
```

Answer (score 3):

The `biopython` module offers this.  Modifying the example in the tutorial (http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec136) slightly:

```
from Bio import Medline, Entrez
pmids = ['18680603', '18665331', '18661158', '18627489', '18627452', '18612381']
Entrez.email = 'your_email@your_address.com'
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="pubmed", id=pmids, rettype="medline", retmode="text")
records = Medline.parse(handle)
# returns a generator containing dicts 
# E.g. to get journal titles back
for record in records:
    print record['JT']   # Abstracts would be record['AB']
```

returns

> ```
> BMC pregnancy and childbirth
> Journal of natural medicines
> Mycorrhiza
> The New phytologist
> Molecular ecology
> PloS one
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Not 100% sure, but I think you can do something very similar using the `metafor` package in R, which is an excellent package for performing meta-analyses...Maybe worth a check.

Comment: As the package author, I appreciate the positive comments about ``metafor``. But just to save the OP a bit of time, ``metafor`` doesn't provide any functionality that does what the OP asked about.